# How to set table cell's color in xcode6?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to iOS development. I am trying to set the background color of table cell to dark blue using xcode storyboard designer view.

The color only shows in designer view. When I launch the app in simulator, I don't see the color as designed.

[image: Designer View shows correct color]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** use

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```